# Convergence of Sample Distributions for Periodic vs Chaotic Systems

Tags: probability, distributions, stochastic-processes, convergence, nonlinear-dynamical-system

Say we have a stochastic process from which we take finite samples to build up some sample probability distribution. As we include more time steps, the sample distribution converges to that of the "true" underlying distribution. I'm curious about the nature of this convergence, particularly how it scales with the total time series length t.

I found this paper: https://doi.org/10.1063/5.0050790, and in it there's the following quote:

"The expected convergence of histograms with time $p(t)=p_0+At^{-C}$ is $C=1/2$ for chaotic and $C=1$ for regular systems."

I can maybe squint and imagine that the $1/2$ comes from the central limit theorem, but what about $C=1$ for "regular systems"? An earlier part of the paper says that $C=1$ is the prediction for periodic systems, so I suppose that's what is meant by a regular system. Could you please point me to a resource that shows where these scaling exponents come from?